# How can I use cache_if method from controller, not view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Inside view, i can write:

```
= cache_if Rails.env.production?, my_cache_key do
  ...
```

But how can I use cache_if method from controller, not view?

Answer (score 2):

[`cache_if`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper.html#method-i-cache_if) is a view helper. It is designed to be mixed in a view context, not in a controller.

You can't use it in a controller. You could try to mix the helper into the controller, but it was not designed for that hence you should not adopt that approach.

Instead, you can use `Rails.cache` to access the cache store. You can then write your own implementation, if you want even cloning the `cache_if` implementation:

```
def cache_if(condition, name = {}, options = nil, &block)
  if condition
    Rails.cache.fetch(name, options, &block)
  else
    yield
  end
end
```